# Overflows not being respected in divs within tables?

Tags: html, css

I am programming a calendar, which can be seen here:

http://8wayrun.com/calendar/month

I have each table cell with a `width: 14%`. This creates the uniformity where each column is the same size. I need this 14% to remain intact.

I'm having an issue however with my overflows. If you look on that page, you can see my events as `7:00 PM - The Break Weekly`, where the word "Weekly" is broken onto a second line. What I would like it to do instead is `7:00 PM - The Break...`. Using an ellipsis overflow.

I have tried the following css:

```
.monthTable .monthMain .monthOccur
{
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

However, this isn't working for me. When I use that code, the `white-space: nowrap` is being respected, but the rest of it isn't. Its expanding the width of the table cell beyond 14%.

Is there a way to fix this without setting fixed pixel widths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `table-layout: fixed;` to `.monthTable`.  This prevents the browser from adjusting the table and respects the widths you set.

Comment: You the best! And it respects the box model for websites with fluid widths.

Answer (score 1):

Set a width to `.monthTable .monthMain .monthOccur`

```
.monthTable .monthMain .monthOccur {
border: 1px solid rgb(50, 50, 50);
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-khtml-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
padding: 5px;
font-size: 11px;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
width: 90%;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't really work because of the CSS box model. It doesn't work unless your website has a fixed width.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (add width):

```
.monthTable .monthMain .monthOccur {
     white-space: nowrap;
     overflow: hidden;
     text-overflow: ellipsis;

     width: 119px;

     border: 1px solid rgb(50, 50, 50);
     -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
     -moz-border-radius: 5px;
     -khtml-border-radius: 5px;
     border-radius: 5px;
     padding: 5px;
     font-size: 11px;
}
```

Here is what it looks now: 
[image: result]

Comment: I asked if there was a way to fix this WITHOUT adding a fixed pixel width.

Comment: in this case as suggested below: width: 90%;